# How to decrypt pubnub messages in pubnub blocks

Tags: pubnub

Im using pubnub encrypted messages https://www.pubnub.com/docs/javascript/api-reference-sdk-v4#init via cipher key between two clientes, now i start intercepting those messages with [PubNub BLOCKS](https://www.pubnub.com/products/blocks/) but can't find a way to decrypt them, i receive a long Base64 string and there is no tool to decrypt it via either the provided [crypto module](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/blocks/crypto-module) or the provided [pubnub module](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/blocks/pubnub-module), the block is super simple

```js
export default (request) => { 

    console.log(request); // Log the request envelope passed when tested with a payload its shown when a real message goes through is a base64 string of an encrypted message

    return request.ok();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Publishing Unencrypted Meta Data with Encrypted Message Paylaod

Currently, if you are using AES encryption the assumption is that you would want end to end encryption and not be able to decrypt the message in-flight by a BLOCK.

However if there is information you want to act on, you [pass the information using the Meta Argument](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/javascript/api-reference-sdk-v4#publish_args).  This meta information is outside the message payload and not encrypted and therefore accessible by a BLOCK.

The PubNub PM team would love to hear more about your use case and why you would want to decrypt this message in flight to see if this is something we need to add to the roadmap. Please send a message to [PubNub Support](https://support.pubnub.com) with more details.

Here is some sample code you can use to see the meta data in action with a block:

### Publishing a message with meta data

The meta data portion of your message is never encrypted and it meant for data that you would use for filtering messages (and other use cases). If you are using an cipher key when you init PubNub, the `message` portion of the payload would be encrypted from end to end (not decrypted within PubNub since we do not know your cipher key). But the `meta` portion would remain clear text so that you can perform condition logic in a block based on these keys/values or for stream filtering on a per client basis.

```js
pubnub.publish(
   {
       channel : "chmeta",
       message : {"text": "hello"},
       meta: { 
           "cool": "beans"
       }
   }, 
   function(status, response) {
       console.log(status, response);
   }
```

);

### Accessing meta data with PubNub BLOCKS

In your block code (Before or After Publish event handlers), you can access the `meta` key as follows:

```js
export default (request) => { 
    console.log(JSON.parse(request.params.meta));
    return request.ok(); 
}
```

The output of the entire `request` parameter would be quite verbose and I encourage you to review it as it will have lots of gems in there you might want to take advantage of, but just honing in on the `meta` key (`request.params.meta`) will give access to the meta data you provided in the `publish`. The `JSON.parse` is needed because the data will be *stringified* (escaped), `{\"cool\": \"beans\"}`, and this will transform it back into a real live JSON object, `{"cool": "beans"}`.

Comment: that didn;t actually answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I did it myself. The code is ugly and I am open to any help with refactoring, but it works - it lets you decrypt messages in PubNub functions (blocks)

Here's the Gist - https://gist.github.com/DataGreed/f0007e7b5b8dcfadd8a44a5d3514b6dc

Don't forget to change the encryption key in `getKey` function.

Answer (score -1):

## PubNub Functions (formerly called BLOCKS) now has Crypto Module

I believe at the time you asked this question, the crypto module was not included with BLOCKS (we rebranded this as PubNub Functions). Now it is:

[PubNub Functions Crypto Module Docs](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/blocks/crypto-module)

Comment: So? It does not support decrypting AES-encoded messages even if you have the key!

Comment: See my answer for the actual answer.

Comment: Even two. First of all, you did not bother to read the original question. It states that there was crypto module at that time and it does not provide any tools for decrypting. Second, you provided a useless answer that did not solve anything. And now it seems you did not even read my comment on why this answer is useless and asking me obvious questions.